# Calculation of Between and Within Subject Standard Deviation

Tags: anova, variance, repeated-measures

I was reading the paper *Applications of the repeatability of quantitative imaging biomarkers: A review of statistical analysis of repeat data sets* and noticed that the while the within-subject standard deviation is the square-root of the within-subject sum of squares, the between-subject standard deviation involves subtracting the within-subject sum of squares from the between-subject sum of squares and then dividing by the number of groups.

Why isn't the between subject standard deviation also simply the square root of the between-subject sum of squares?

The formulas are included below; where, Y_i represents the mean across K repetitions, Y-bar is the mean of all observations, Y_ik are individual measurements, n is the number of participants.

Thanks in advance.